# Maxwell speed distribution of a mixture of gases vs. of one gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

How is it qualitatively justifiable that, in a mixture of molecules of different kinds in complete equilibrium, each kind of molecule has the same Maxwellian distribution in speed that it would have if the other kinds were not present?

Comment: One way of looking at this is: if one specie had a different distribution it'd probably have a different temperature, violating your equilibrium premis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the base of the Maxwellian velocity distribution, there are three key ingredients:

1. the equipartition theorem, connecting the average value of each component of the velocity with the temperature of the system (it is important to connect the average value of each cartesian component of velocity to the temperature);
2. the central limit theorem (CLT), which ensures a gaussian distribution of each component of the velocity of one particle since it may be considered as the sum of a huge number of variations due to the other particles. Notice that CLT holds under very mild assumption on the distribution of velocity variations);
3. the statistical independence of each component of the velocity of one particle on any other component of the velocity of the same or other particles. Such a hypothesis is certainly satisfied for a system at equilibrium with a thermostat at temperature $T$ since, under such conditions, there is no constraint on the velocities.

All these three points together are enough to imply the Maxwellian distribution. Consequently, that each kind of molecule has the same Maxwellian distribution in speed that it would have if the other species were not present.

Comment: Can you explain the third point in more depth? I don't quite understand why each component of a particle's velocity does not affect its other velocity components, nor other particles' velocities.

Comment: @DarthBaguette A thermostat may exchange energy without limits (physically, it is a large system). This implies that each component of velocity may vary without limits and global constraints. The same would not be true if the total energy would be fixed. In this case, more energy in one component of one particle and less energy for the other components and particles.